# Open button in new window?

Tags: javascript, html, button, window, new-operator

How would I go about making the button open in a new window, emulating "a href, target = _blank"?

I currently have:

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com';"> 
     <span class="icon">Open</span>
</button>
```

The button isn't in a form, I just want to make it open in a new window.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Opens a new window with the url you supplied :)

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com');">
     <span class="icon">Open</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Add "return false;" after onClick event to avoid form submit.

Comment: onClick="window.open( yourUrl , '_top');" to open in same tab.

Comment: In google chrome, this code only opens a new tab in the same window. Would it be possible to open a new browser window with javascript?

Comment: To create a dynamic link based on another input field: `onClick="window.open(`http://lecrat.fr/articleSearchSaisie.php?recherche=${document.getElementById('grossesse-crat').value}`); return false;"`

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get your method to work @Damien-at-SF...

So I resorted to my old knowledge.

By encasing the input type="button" within a hyperlink element, you can simply declare the target property as so:

```
<a href="http://www.site.org" target="_blank">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Open" />
</a>
```

The 'target="_blank"' is the property which makes the browser open the link within a new tab. This attribute has other properties, See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp for further details.

Since the 'value=""' attribute on buttons will write the contained string to the button, a span is not necessary.

Instead of writing:

```
<element></element>
```

for most HTML elements you can simply close them with a trailing slash, like so:

```
<element />
```

Oh, and finally...  a 'button' element has a refresh trigger within it, so I use an 'input type[button]' to avoid triggering the form.

Good Luck Programmers.

Due to StackOverflow's policy I had to change the domain in the example:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(); return false;" value="click me" />
```

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 5):

You can acheive this using `window.open()` method, passing `_blank` as one of the parameter. You can refer the below links which has more information on this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you strictly want to stick to using button,Then simply create an open window function as follows:

```
    <script>
function myfunction() {
    window.open("mynewpage.html");
}
</script>
```

Then in your html do the following with your button:

Join

So you would have something like this:

```
 <body>
    <script>
function joinfunction() {
    window.open("mynewpage.html");
}
</script>
<button  onclick="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-default subs-btn">Join</button>
```