# Changing existing html tag with javascript (open btn site in new window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have (not my site, I just want to change the function of it using greasemonkey) has this button below;

```
 <input name="1$Main$Edit" value="Edit"
        onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'; return false;"
        id="l_Main_Edit" title="Edit" class="whitebtn" type="submit">
```

How can I change this (in greasemonkey) so whenever I click on it, it then opens in a new tab? Note that the site is different per button therefore I would not want to change/replace that. 
I've tried searching around but could never find a definitive answer as it involves entering the url myself in the edit as well.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643958/open-button-in-new-window)? It seems to provide an answer to your issue

Comment: How would I go about replacing onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'; into  onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/');? Keep in mind the url has to be copied from the existing onclick into the new onclick as well. There doesn't seem to be any outerhtml replace function afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the URL with regex and override the click event to open to a _blank target?

```
$(':input.whitebtn').click(function() {
    window.open(
        $(this).attr('onclick').match(/window\.location\.href\s*=\s*['"](.*)['"];/)[1],
        '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2b95fsqj/1/

Comment: Seems to work on jsfiddle but not on the actual site in question... could it be that its somehow blocked from them using their own javascript? The site in question is playerauctions.com (you would need to register, create an offer/sell and then click myaccount>my offers. It's the edit button that I want to open in new window.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<input name="1$Main$Edit" value="Edit"
        onclick="return doIt('https://www.google.com/');"
        id="l_Main_Edit" title="Edit" class="whitebtn" type="submit">
...
function doIt(loc){
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = loc;
   a.target = '_blank';
   a.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the onclick attribute of the input tag will always be present and always appear in this format, you could do:

```js
$('input.whitebtn').click(function(event) {
  // This will prevent the button's default onclick behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // This will grab the URL from the onclick attribute
  var url = $(this).attr('onclick').split("'")[1];

  // This will open the URL in a new tab or window
  window.open(url);
});
```

Note that there is no way to force a URL to open in a new tab instead of a new window. The browser will always use the user's setting on the matter.

If your goal is to force the above link to open in a new tab instead of in the same tab, this should work.